# Cannot use null as default value for parameter in PHP-8

Tags: php, class, nullable, php-8, property-promotion

In php-8 and older versions the following code works

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(string $string = null) {}
}
```

But in php-8, along with property promotion, it throws an error

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(private string $string = null) {}
}
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use null as default value for parameter $string of type string

Making the string nullable works though

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(private ?string $string = null) {}
}
```

So is this a bug too or intended behaviour?

Comment: Why would you think it's a bug? The error message makes it pretty clear this is intentional

Comment: @Phil because AFAIK nullable is not required for null as default value, isn't it? It doesn't throw error when `private` is removed, thus the doubt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the [RFC for Constructor Property Promotion](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion)

> ...because promoted parameters imply a property declaration, nullability must be explicitly declared, and is not inferred from a null default value:
>
> ```php
> class Test {
>     // Error: Using null default on non-nullable property
>     public function __construct(public Type $prop = null) {}
>  
>     // Correct: Make the type explicitly nullable instead
>     public function __construct(public ?Type $prop = null) {}
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug!

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(private string $string = null) {}
}
```

The above code is a short hand syntax to

```
class Foo {
    private string $string = null;
    public function __construct(string $string) {
        $this->string  = $string;
    }
}
```

Which generates a fatal error

> Fatal error: Default value for property of type string may not be
> null.

So you can't initialize a typed property that is not nullable to `NULL`